# Origine onomatopéique de « chatouiller »

Tags: étymologie, onomatopées

Étonnamment, « chatouiller » serait une onomatopée. Pourquoi ?

> Chatouiller pourrait également être rapproché du latin catullire (être
> en chaleur) qui aurait évolué en catulliare et aurait eu le sens de «
> faire éprouver » <sup>2</sup>. L'hypothèse la plus probable reste celle d'une
> **origine onomatopéique** car la succession de consonnes « k-t-l » se
> retrouve dans plusieurs langues indo-européennes <sup>3</sup>.

Source: [Chatouillement: Étymologie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatouillement#.C3.89tymologie) (Wikipédia).

> chatouiller, *verbe transitif* (**onomatopée**)

Source: [Chatouiller](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chatouiller/14924) (Larousse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'étymologie onomatopéique probable signalée par [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatouillement#.C3.89tymologie) est celle qui figure dans le *Dictionnaire historique en langue française* (sld Alain Rey) qui la qualifie aussi de probable, mais ce qui manque (ce qui me manque du moins car mes connaissances en linguistique sont certainement trop limitées pour ça) c'est en quoi la succession des consonnes *k-t-l* représente une onomatopée. Avant d'être employé pour décrire une sensation agréable le mot dont chatouiller est issu (*catellier*) signifiait seulement « provoquer des tressaillements » avec une valeur neutre mais ceci ne me dit pas non plus pourquoi les consonnes *k-t-l* ont une valeur onomatopéique.

Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/chatouiller) reprend l'évolution étymologique du mot donnée par Alain Rey et ses collègues, évolution qui rend tout à fait improbable l'hypothèse d'un rapprochement avec le bas allemand ou néerlandais *katelen* (dérivé de *kat* du latin *cattus*, chat), chatouiller se disant *kietelen* en néerlandais.

Comment: Oui, il nous manque une information. Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on parle d'onomatopée dans le dictionnaire sans même avoir d'indice sur le bruit qui aurait pu construire le mot.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert Il y a une discussion à ce sujet sur [Projet Babel](http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3635) mais elle n'apporte, à mon avis,  aucun élément scientifique supplémentaire (et à corriger en néerlandais chatouiller se dit *kietelen* et pas *katelen* - la personne qui cite ce mot  n'avait pas à mon avis bien compris la dérivation de *kietelen* à *katelen* proposée comme étymologie par  [Sainéan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazare_Sain%C3%A9an) et que les études ultérieures ont réfutée).

Answer (score 0):

Le Robert écrit : peut-être de *chat* ou du néerlandais *katelen* [je n'ai pas trouvé de traducteur connaissant sa signification en français, de plus, Laure a posté un commentaire pour dénier cette étymologie].

*Touiller* : remuer, agiter : touiller une sauce.

Essayez de *remuer un chat*, ou plus prosaïquement *caresser un chat* en stimulant ses zones sensibles, en le chahutant un peu : il va avoir des réactions nerveuses agréables comme lorsqu'on caresse une enfant (souvent appelé mon minou, mon p'tit chat, ...) sous la plante des pieds, sous les aisselles ou aux endroits où l'on *fait guili-guili* (synonyme de chatouiller).

Certes ce n'est pas une explication académique, mais plausible après tout !

Comment: *Le dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (nld Alain Rey) réfute (étymologie historique à l'appui) l'hypothèse d'un emprunt au néerlandais *katelen* au bas allemand ou au néerlandais *katelen*, qu'il qualifie d’étymologie seconde, populaire.

Comment: Je ne vois pas le lien avec l'onomatopée ?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert On joue à chat-touille : le premier qui touche l'autre peut lui faire des guili-guili. Ce ne serait alors pas une onomatopée, mais un mot composé pour un jeu d'enfants fort plaisant ... pourquoi pas ?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert P.S. : je n'ai pas les compétences linguistiques pour valider quoi que ce soit, mais *jouer à chat* est un jeu d'enfants, jouer à *[si tu es ]chat-[ je te ]touille* indiquerait plutôt pourquoi ce mot est toujours en usage, *chat* et *touiller* son encore du vocabulaire courant ; s'il n'y avait cet 'effet de miroir sémantique' seule l'onomatopée *guili-guili* aurait du rester

Comment: @cl-r Sauf que le mot n'a pris le sens actuel (connotation agréable de la chatouille qu'au XVè siècle) et que le mot *catellier* dont il est issu (et ça les linguistes en sont sûrs) voulait dire « provoquer des tressaillements », pas tellement de rapport avec un jeu d'enfant qui, s'il est poétique, n'a pas de fondement scientifique.

Comment: @Laure *Titiller* (*tetiller* 1190 ; rare avant la fin du XVIIIe ; du latin titillare : « Chatouiller de manière à provoquer une démangeaison légère et agréable ». Synonyme : chatouiller - Le Robert) devrait alors être employé pour chatouiller, si l'on a une lecture méthodologique de l'évolution de la langue. À mon sens, le glissement sémantique ne vient pas de l'écrit, mais de l'oreille et de la réorganisation des phonèmes porteurs d'émotions et de perceptions intrinsèques du réel. De cette écoute intuitive *au présent* on a l'évolution : *catellier → chatouille → papouille*... sans garantie!

Answer (score 0):

« Ça chatouille, touille, touille ».

Pour moi  (et oui, d’accord, moi et mes oreilles sont non-Francophones) « touille-touille » ressemble déjà un peu à « guili-guili », et si l’on considère que « [Chatouillis](http://encyclopedie_universelle.fracademic.com/46893/guili-guili) » est donné comme alternative « Familière » pour « guili-guili », dans l’Encyclopédie Universelle, ce n’est pas impossible que c’est l’onomatopée que nous associons aujourd’hui avec « chatouiller » (c'est-à-dire « guili-guili ») qui a évoluée de « touille-touille » puis à « touilli-touilli » et puis finalement à « guili-guili ».

Pour tenter « d’expliquer » le « G » dans « guili-guili » (au lieu du « T »), (et aussi pour parler du sens « titiller »/agréable de chatouiller dont cl-r parle dans sa réponse et ses commentaires) , au [Picardie il y a(vait) le mot « dé**G**atouiller »](https://books.google.com/books?id=M34NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=D%C3%89GATOUILLER&source=bl&ots=RsE2uZjEDY&sig=WODRn7QRoff8yqHDiDRFC9O0pSE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0-CeVIquL4r7gwSIsYOwBg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=D%C3%89GATOUILLER%20titillari&f=false), venant de « de » NON-privatif et « **G**atouiller », qui porte un « G », aussi bien que le sens agréable de chatouiller (« titiller »).

Comment: On s'en approche, j'ai l'impression :-) Bonne analyse